# Is there any alternative to using the "body" attribute for using OpenAPI/Swagger with "aws_api_gateway_rest_api"?

Tags: swagger, terraform, aws-api-gateway, openapi, terraform-provider-aws

I'm using terraform to create an "aws_api_gateway_rest_api". I'd like to use OpenAPI/Swagger to define the API. Right now I'm using a "template_file" to generate the final OpenAPI JSON as the body attribute. Something like this:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "myapi" {
  name        = "MYAPI"
  endpoint_configuration {
    types = ["REGIONAL"]
  }
  binary_media_types = [
    "application/json"
  ]
  body = "${data.template_file.swagger.rendered}"
}
```

This works fine unless I also have an authorizer:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_authorizer" "cognito_authorizer" {
  name            = "cognito-authorizer"
  rest_api_id     = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.myapi.id
  identity_source = "method.request.header.Authorization"
  type            = "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
  provider_arns   = ["${aws_cognito_user_pool.pool.arn}"]
}
```

The authorizer is referenced in the api definition file by name:

```
"security": [
                    {
                        "cognito-authorizer": [
                            "cognito-authorizer"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
```

The obvious problem is, that terraform deploys the API resources and methods *before* the authorizer was created:

1. Create API and all resources, methods (referenced authorizer doesn't exist yet)
2. Create authorizer

Terraform "apply" doesn't show any problems, but the deployed api methods don't have the authorizer enabled.

The problem only exists when using the "body" attribute. If I define the API resources, methods and integrations directly in terraform, the dependencies can be resolved just fine, as the order  of creation is:

1. Create API resource
2. Create Authorizer
3. Create resources, methods and integrations (referenced authorizer exists)

What I would need is a terraform resource that does the same thing as the body attribute, but separate from API creation. Is there any alternative to using the "body" attribute for using OpenAPI/Swagger with "aws_api_gateway_rest_api"?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create the authorizers using OpenAPI, so they don't need to be created in terraform. I accidentially found out by using the export function in the console when trying to convert my api.json to OpenAPI 3.0. In OpenAPI 3.0 the declaration looks like the code snippet from my template file below. I have two authorizers, the one from the question and a custom one which I include here, as it might help someone:

```
"components": {
    "securitySchemes": {
      "cognito-authorizer": {
        "type": "apiKey",
        "name": "Authorization",
        "in": "header",
        "x-amazon-apigateway-authtype": "cognito_user_pools",
        "x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer": {
          "providerARNs": [
            "${cognito_userpool}"
          ],
          "type": "cognito_user_pools"
        }
      },
      "tenant_authorizer": {
        "type": "apiKey",
        "name": "Authorization",
        "in": "header",
        "x-amazon-apigateway-authtype": "custom",
        "x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer": {
          "authorizerUri": "${authorizer_uri}",
          "authorizerCredentials": "${authorizer_credentials}",
          "authorizerResultTtlInSeconds": 300,
          "type": "token"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```